# jQuery (::after) selector issue

Tags: jquery, css

In a css style I have the following

```
.back::after  {
    content: "";
    background-image: url(../images/patch.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    opacity: 0.6;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;

}
```

anyway using jQuery : `$(".back ::after").css("opacity","0.9")` to select the `::after` element to change opacity doesnt work ! any idea how to do this ?

Comment: You can't select it because pseudo elements don't exist in the DOM.

Comment: thanks , any work around ?

Comment: @JoshC the duplicate post will not work for a visual style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well , thanks for the neat solutions , but i think this one fits me the most as i can control it easily , injecting my own style dynamically and removing it.

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('.back::after { opacity: 0.9 !important; }', 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned, you cannot target the pseudo-elements, because they don't really exist in the DOM.

You could simply add an additional CSS rule and target the related element instead:

```
.back.focus::after  {
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

and

```
$('.back').addClass('focus');
```

Comment: this is a neat work around :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Try just using one colon, i.e.: `.back:after`. Leave a comment if it still doesn't work.

Comment: That's not the issue in this case. Even with one colon, it still won't work.

Comment: You might want to read up on `::after` and `:after`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after. Basically in CSS3, pseudo-elements start with `::` and pseudo-selectors with `:`.

Comment: Thanks both. I've learnt something!